# table not staying in div within content page Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, blogs

I have a `div` on the homepage and I call a content page which contains a table, it works perfectly and re-sizes and fits in neatly, when I do the exact same thing in another `div` that is in a content page that uses a separate template it doesn't work.

Its easiest if I show you..
Home page , bottom left where it says "Current Standings"
limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms

and now the page , http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/?page_id=110
if you look to the left at current standings, the table is clearly expand far beyond the div. I don't expect it to be perfect because they are different width divs, but ive even tried playing around with the width and made it the same as the home page but it still doesn't work.

Are there certain rules being applied here that I need to get rid of?

Also, here is the code for calling the content

```
$post_id = 989;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo apply_filters('the_content',$queried_post->post_content);
?>
```

Ive also tried `display:table` in the div but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit style.css and do the following:

Line 133 - remove `width: 20px;`

Line 109 - remove `padding: 2px 5px;`

Line 1627 - remove `text-indent: 15px;`

Fix this only for the left sidebar, so that it doesn't impact the other tables.

Comment: Thanks Lazar, I adjusted the text-indent and that sorted it. It still needs fixing but thats a table issue , not CSS, as for the other 2 lines to edit I couldnt quite find them! But it seems fine anyway, just needs fixing table wise on my part.